# Transfer ether between two addressrd using call

Tags: transfer, eoa, eth-call, address.call

I have this code:

```
function regAgent(uint[] memory _preferences) notOwner onlyBeforeEnd public {
    require(msg.sender.balance - fee >= 0, "You can't pay the fee.");
    require(!registered[msg.sender], "Agent is already registered.");
    Agent memory newAgent = Agent(agents.length, msg.sender, _preferences);
    agents.push(newAgent);
    registered[msg.sender] = true;
    (bool success, ) = owner.call.value(100)("");
    // the agent must pay the fee to participate
    // owner must recieve that fee
}
```

It is assumed that a participant calls that function, pays a fee, and that fee is paid to the address of the owner (the person who deployed the SC). But there is something that is not clear to me... If I add this line `(bool success, ) = owner.call.value(100)("");` the owner is supposed to receive 100 (gwei, ethers?). But who gives it to him? How do I get the participant to transfer his ether to the owner?

Could anyone show me an example? Any info is welcome too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A contract only has access to its own funds.

```
(bool success, ) = owner.call.value(100)("");
```

This code send 100 wei from the contract's balance to owner address.

If no units is given solidity assumes it is wei, 1 ether = 10^18 wei.

---

In order to make a function accept ether payments it has to be declared as payable, then `msg.value` will contain the sent amount.

```
function buy(uint256 itemId) public payable {
    require(msg.value >= 0.01 ether, "Not enough ether sent");

    // Sent ethers to wallet 
    uint256 amount = msg.value;
    payable(wallet).transfer(amount);

    // Generate event
    emit ItemSold(itemId, amount);
}
```

Comment: Oh... I didn't know that. And... how could I send ether yo SC? How can I take the SC address? But could it be done the other way around? (the participant must pay money into the SC fund)

Comment: @Joncarre I've added an example how to use together with payable to require the user to send ethers and forward them to a recipient wallet.